# Pandas DataFrame: Find index values for sequences of a certain length where two columns are equal/identical

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` which is defined like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd


data = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [4, 4],
        [4, 4], [5, 5], [5, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.index = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1), periods=len(df), freq='H')

print(df)
```

and yields:

```
                 A  B
2012-01-01 00:00:00  1  1
2012-01-01 01:00:00  1  1
2012-01-01 02:00:00  2  2
2012-01-01 03:00:00  2  2
2012-01-01 04:00:00  2  2
2012-01-01 05:00:00  3  3
2012-01-01 06:00:00  4  4
2012-01-01 07:00:00  4  4
2012-01-01 08:00:00  4  4
2012-01-01 09:00:00  5  5
2012-01-01 10:00:00  5  5
```

**Now I am trying to get the index of the rows where column A and B are equal AND at least (or exactly would also be sufficient) n consecutive rows (here hours) are equal in `A` and `B` i.e. I want to extract the index values that have to be consecutive (slices of length >= n) where `A` and `B` are equal.**

So in this case for n=2 it should be the index for the "twos" and "fours":

```
2012-01-01 02:00:00
2012-01-01 03:00:00
2012-01-01 04:00:00
2012-01-01 06:00:00
2012-01-01 07:00:00
2012-01-01 08:00:00
```

Getting only the index for the rows where `A` and `B` are equal is straightforward.

But how can I fetch only n consecutive equal elements?

I guess there must be some fancy groupby approach that I don't see at the moment..

Comment: Why in the example you gave wouldn't the index for "one" and "five" be outputed?

Comment: Because there are only two lines of equal "fives" and n=2 so only 3 lines of equal numbers are returned

Comment: Still not clear why 1 & 5 are not included in the returned set.  Both are examples of n=2 consecutive rows where A & B are equal.

Comment: @JohnE The first row of each grouping would be excluded per those rules, which is included in the OP's expected output.

Comment: good point.  Let me try again.  4 conditions must be True:  `(A=B) & (A.shift()= B.shift()) & (A=A.shift(+1) or A.shift(-1)) & size of group >= n`  Or something kinda like that.  ;-)

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for both answers which both work like a charm! The n=2 was a typo and should be n>2. Should I adapt it?

Comment: I was too quick. The answers didn't work for my real example. See my comment below.

Comment: O.k., the first error was because one int column wasn't converted to float64 but int64..

Comment: FYI, I deleted my answer.  It looks like you need to have consecutive values and @alexander's approach makes more sense in that case

Comment: Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per your description, I am not clear why 1 & 5 would be excluded from your results since they each contain 2 or more consecutive rows with matching values for A & B.

The solution below should still help, however, and I'm sure you can modify it to suit your needs.  It first filters the dataframe for matching values in columns `A` and `B` (`df_matching`).  It then uses the *shift-cumsum* pattern to group on consecutive matching values and then filters on `n`.

```
n = 2
df_matching = df[df.A == df.B]
gb = df_matching.groupby((df_matching.A != df_matching.A.shift()).cumsum())
df_target = gb.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= n)

>>> df_target
                     A  B
2012-01-01 00:00:00  1  1
2012-01-01 01:00:00  1  1
2012-01-01 02:00:00  2  2
2012-01-01 03:00:00  2  2
2012-01-01 04:00:00  2  2
2012-01-01 06:00:00  4  4
2012-01-01 07:00:00  4  4
2012-01-01 08:00:00  4  4
2012-01-01 09:00:00  5  5
2012-01-01 10:00:00  5  5
```

The dataframe above is to ensure that it conforms to your expectation.  Then just extract the index:

```
>>> df_target.index
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2012-01-01 02:00:00', '2012-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2012-01-01 04:00:00', '2012-01-01 06:00:00',
               '2012-01-01 07:00:00', '2012-01-01 08:00:00',
               '2012-01-01 09:00:00', '2012-01-01 10:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note that you get your expected result if `n=3`.

Comment: This works but I have some consecutive equal elements < n in the first and last entries of `df_target`.

Comment: I tried again. It's working with the example dataframe I provided here but not with my real data (which holds float values).

Comment: With my real data (float, more columns, more rows) it is working until `gb = df_matching...` but then returns an empty dataframe/index. Actually, I don't understand why..

Comment: Even with the fixed column data type.

Comment: Perhaps it is an issue with the precision of your floating point numbers.  Try, for example, df_matching.A.round(5) != df_matching.A.round(5).shift()

Comment: I'll figure it out. Nevertheless, you have already answered my question and this is some other issue. Thanks!